# Javascript web service request in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web-services

I have been trying for the past few days to use JavaScript to call a web service. The web service returns an xml file of the form:

```
<element1> 
  <element1a attribute="x">
   <element1aa attribute="1" />
   <element1ab attribute="2" />
   .....
   <element1an attribute="n" />
  <element1a />
<element1/>

<element2> 
  <element2a attribute="y">
   <element2aa attribute="1" />
   <element2ab attribute="2" />
   .....
   <element2an attribute="n" />
  <element2a />
<element2/>
```

The user is supposed to click on a link, then a new, simple HTML page loads, contacts the web service and the javascript parses the returned xml file (on the fly) and presents the first three results of element1 and element2 and their attributes. This information is presented as a simple HTML table. If the user reloads the page, the table contents are updated (with the new values).

I have been doing a lot of studying, but I am not sure if this can be done. Whatever I used, is not working.

Does anybody know if this can be done? Can you advice on how - I would be more than grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume `<element1a />`, `<element1 />`, `<element2a />`, and `<element2 />` are all meant to be `</elementX>`. If what you have there is an actual copy-and-paste, the problem is that your XML is malformed.

Comment: *"Whatever I used, is not working."* Which was?

Comment: Yes, this can be done, using JavaScript, `XMLHttpRequest`, and the DOM. Are you open to using libraries to make your life easier? jQuery, et. al.? It would shorten the script required markedly.

Comment: Please ignore the XML structure above, I just wanted to make it "easier" for people to understand what I need. The XML file is perfectly structured.
I have been using all examples out there, but nothing seems to work. 
Yes, I am open to using jQuery, if it is easy to use. I have limited exposure to JavaScript and none with Web Services.

Comment: The thing that I forgot to mention is that this is a small app that I try to create that will run on a mobile phone's browser. Will jQuery work?

Comment: @ user: Yes (in fact, there's a jQuery Mobile for exactly that), but it increases the download size.